# Set Bar color according to data in CF chart

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart

I am creating a bar graph in CF11 .Is it possible to give different colors for the different bars in CFchartseries according to the data.

```
<cfchartseries serieslabel="Rent" type="bar" colorlist="barcolr_list">
        <cfloop index="counter" from=1 to="#ArrayLen(PropName_arry)-1#" step="1">               
        <cfchartdata item="#PropName_arry[counter]#" value="#Grossrent_arry[counter]#" >        
    </cfloop>
</cfchartseries>
```

I read in docs that the colorlist attribute is  available for pie,pyramid..etc graph .
How can i set different colors to bars according to the grossrent value

ie, if the grossrent > 800 the bar color should be red
else it should be blue

This code worked in CF7 .But not worked in CF11

Comment: Have you read the docs for `<cfchart>` etc, and what have you tried? Where's your code? What did you have difficulty with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ColorList only works for chart types pie, pyramid, area, horizontalbar, cone, cylinder, or step. [cfchartseries](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfchartseries).

You can create specific colors for each column 2 different ways. Through rules or through a list of styles.

You can create a rule which is added to the plot attribute. Specify a colour that applies to that rule. Below example shows rules when the x axis value is true.

```
<cfset plot= {"rules": [
    {"rule":"'%k'=='2007'",
     "background-color":"purple"},
    {"rule":"'%k'=='2008'",
     "background-color":"pink"},
    {"rule":"'%k'=='2009'",
     "background-color":"green"}]}
    >
```

Or you can create a list of styles for the chart using the styles attribute in plot.

```
<cfset plot = {"styles":[
{
"background-color":"##e95d22"
},
{
"background-color":"##017890"
},
{
"background-color":"##da534d"
},
{
"background-color":"##4a266d"
},
{
"background-color":"##f4913c"
}]}>
```

Include the plot variable in the chart element like this.

```
<cfchart format="png" chartheight="180" chartwidth="233" showlegend="false" style="test.js" plot="#plot#">
<cfchartseries type="bar">
    <cfchartdata item="2005" value="1000"/>
    <cfchartdata item="2006" value="3000"/>
    <cfchartdata item="2007" value="1000"/>
    <cfchartdata item="2008" value="4000"/>
    <cfchartdata item="2009" value="2000"/>
</cfchartseries>
```

To help with my example here is my test.js

```
{
"graphset":[
    {
    "border-width":1, 
    "background-color":"transparent",
    "plotarea":{"margin":"dynamic"}
}]
}
```

Both these techniques can be included directly through the test.js file as well but to make these colours dynamic it is easier to enter them through the plot attribute.

Comment: It Worked  thank you very much now i am facing difficulties with the x axis labels.Please help me on this.I have many cfcharts in my application. There are 32 X-axis labels, in one of my cfcharts, but only 18 of them are displaying. Other than that, the chart displays properly, but the x-axis labels are missing.

I have used JSON style for applying styles to chart and the Items-Overlap attribute of ScaleX is set to false.

How do I display all labels in X-axis without skipping any?